# Convergence in mean of increasing random variables

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n$ takes the value $0$ or $n$ with probability $1$. Let $a>0$ be such that $E(X_n) < a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $E(X_n) \uparrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

> Can one conclude that $E|X_n - a| \rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

We can write $X_n = n 1_{ A_n }$, where $A_n$ is the set on which $X_n = n$. Then $E(X_n)= n P (A_n) \uparrow a < \infty$. This means that $P(A_n)$ has to somehow balance the $n$ by going to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not, since when $n>2a$ we have $|X_n-a|\ge a$ with probability $1$, so that $E|X_n-a|\ge a$ at the very least. (I suspect that $E|X_n-a|\to 1+a$.)

Comment: I think the inequality should not be strict, as $X_n$ may be $0$ after $n > 2a$ as well.