# Shift the sequence of random variables to make it converge to $0$ in mean

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, random-variables

This is a follow-up to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550493/convergence-in-mean-of-increasing-random-variables).

Let $(X_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n$ takes the value $0$ or $n$ with probability $1$. Let $a>0$ be such that $E(X_n) < a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $E(X_n) \uparrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

> Is it possible to find a number $b$ such that $E|X_n - b| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

We can write $X_n = n 1_{ A_n }$, where $A_n$ is the set on which $X_n = n$. Then $E(X_n)= n P (A_n) \uparrow a < \infty$. This means that $P(A_n)$ has to somehow balance the $n$ by going to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X_n=p_n \delta_{n} + (1-p_n)\delta_{0}$ and note that $E(X_n) = np_n$, so that $np_n\to a$.

Next, $E(|X_n-b|) = p_n|n-b|+(1-p_n)|b|\geq p_n|n-b|$. But $\lim_n p_n|n-b| = a>0$, so $E(|X_n-b|)$ cannot converge to $0$.

Comment: Why does $p_n |n - b|$ converge to $a$?

Comment: @Holden $p_n|n-b|\sim p_n n$

Comment: Do $\delta_n$ and $\delta_0$ denote Dirac measures?; i.e. when you write $X_n = p_n \delta_n + ( 1 - p_n ) \delta_0$, does "=" stand for "distributed as"?

Comment: @Holden yes ${}{}$